# A Game I Made Won't End

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I run the following X&O game everything goes as planned. However, when someone wins and the game is supposed to end, the game then follows despite the fact that it printed "Game Over."

```
player1 = input("What is the first player's name? ")
player2 = input("What is the second player's name? ")
board = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]


def game(player1, player2, board, i):
    if i <= 9:
        print('\n' + 'This is the current state of the board' + '\n' + str(board[0]) + '|' + str(board[1]) + '|' +
              str(board[2]) + '\n' + str(board[3]) + '|' + str(board[4]) + '|' + str(board[5]) + '\n' +
              str(board[6]) + '|' + str(board[7]) + '|' + str(board[8]))
        actions(player1, player2, board, i)
        print('\n' + 'This is the current state of the board' + '\n' + str(board[0]) + '|' + str(board[1]) + '|' +
              str(board[2]) + '\n' + str(board[3]) + '|' + str(board[4]) + '|' + str(board[5]) + '\n' +
              str(board[6]) + '|' + str(board[7]) + '|' + str(board[8]))
```

This part above is to intiate the game and determine when the number of turns exceeds the wanted amount.

```
def actions(player1, player2, board, j):
    if j % 2 == 1:
        print(player1 + "'s turn")
        play = int(input('In which position do you want to play? ')) - 1
        if board[play] == 'x' or board[play] == 'o':
            print('This is an invalid play')
            actions(player1, player2, board, j)
        else:
            board[play] = 'x'
            j += 1
            checking(player1, player2, board, j)

    elif j % 2 == 0:
        print(player2 + "'s turn")
        play = int(input('In which position do you want to play? ')) - 1
        if board[play] == 'x' or board[play] == 'o':
            print('This is an invalid play')
            actions(player1, player2, board, j)
        else:
            board[play] = 'o'
            j += 1
            checking(player1, player2, board, j)
```

This part above is the main game logic. It takes the players input and use it to change the board state.

```
def checking(player1, player2, board, j):
    for x in (0, 3, 6):
        if board[x] == board[x + 1] == board[x + 2] == 'x':
            print(player1 + ' wins!')
            print('Game Over')
            game(player1, player2, board, 10)
        elif board[x] == board[x + 1] == board[x + 2] == 'o':
            print(player2 + ' wins!')
            print('Game Over')
            game(player1, player2, board, 10)
        else:
            pass
    for x in (0, 1, 2):
        if board[x] == board[x + 3] == board[x + 6] == 'x':
            print(player1 + ' wins!')
            print('Game Over')
            game(player1, player2, board, 10)
        elif board[x] == board[x + 3] == board[x + 6] == 'o':
            print(player2 + ' wins!')
            print('Game Over')
            game(player1, player2, board, 10)
        else:
            pass
    if board[0] == board[4] == board[8] == 'x':
        print(player1 + ' wins!')
        print('Game Over')
        game(player1, player2, board, 10)
    elif board[0] == board[4] == board[8] == 'o':
        print(player2 + ' wins!')
        print('Game Over')
        game(player1, player2, board, 10)
    elif board[2] == board[4] == board[6] == 'x':
        print(player1 + ' wins!')
        print('Game Over')
        game(player1, player2, board, 10)
    elif board[2] == board[4] == board[6] == 'o':
        print(player2 + ' wins!')
        print('Game Over')
        game(player1, player2, board, 10)
    else:
        game(player1, player2, board, j)
```

This part above uses the current state of the board after each play and checks if the player who just played won or not.

```
game(player1, player2, board, 1)
```

Comment: Well… even if you print "Game over", you're still calling `game()` again…

Comment: Try to call `return` after printing `"game over"`

Comment: I too wish my computer understood human languages instead of me having to write code, I truly do.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm calling `game()` with the turn value i = 10. Wouldn't that make the if-statement `if i <= 9:` False, and thus it wouldn't call actions. What's the problem with that logic?

Answer (score 2):

printing does not end your game, it just prints.

If you want to end the game you need to actually exit it.

You are printing game over, and then calling the game again, making it start again.

You should instead make it `return "Game Over"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked for me. However, I have a question. When I was calling game(), I changed the number of turns to 10, 'game(player1, player2, board, 10)'

Comment: sorry what's the question? how to reduce number of turns?

Comment: Why wouldn't the game end there? The change made the number of turns into 10, so the if-statement is False, and It then wouldn't call `actions()`.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your code doesn't really have an end:

```
def game(player1, player2, board, i):
    if i <= 9:
        (current state)
        actions(player1, player2, board, i)
```

So essentially, if you're within 9 turns, show the current state and call function `actions()'. However, there is no check whether the game is over yet or not, or what to do when it's over. You're just letting it run out of turns without an alternative

You could use and `else` statements to be more deterministic, or use `while - False`.